# Trying to find a plant in SC

Tags: identification

Help! I'm trying to find a plant that I only remember from childhood. It was in SC, i remember it was soon after frost because I was eating persimmons. The plant I'm looking for smelled very much like pepper, I can't remember much on what or looked like except that it may have had white/speckled tiny flowers?  It was about 2-3 feet high I think. Again this was years ago so my memory is probably screwed, I just really remember the strong pepper smell. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! Could you please add at least a few more details - indoors or outside (garden or wilderness), an ideal of the leaves, flower size, anything?

Comment: It was in the woods beside a cow path... The flowers were small, about the size of queens Ann's lace flowers. (If they actually were flowers at all). It's been over 10 ago so this may be a futile attempt.thats really all I can remember. :/